# Effective way to mapping csv data to class or struct?

Tags: c#, csv, unity-game-engine

I am using Unity engine and want to know about effective CSV data mapping.

Now I'm parsing the csv data and mapping the data to the class's MemberInfo, FieldInfo, etc. This is a way of using reflection, so data loading performance is significantly lower.

I would like to know if there is another recommended method.
I want to create a CSV parser for generic class or struct.

Comment: For this kind of content a CSV file structure is way too flat I guess .. what happens if you have a lot of nested stuff? You should rather have a look at [XML serialization](http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php/Saving_and_Loading_Data:_XmlSerializer)

Comment: Thanks to response.
I'm already using XMLSerialization or Json for a lot of nested stuffs.
That's are our team's other game designer's request, so I want to increase loading performance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSV does not offer any way to tell which field means what, that means parsing is feeding that extra information manually. Just use a JSON and be done with it. 
if you are worried about performance you can always switch to a more performant format further down the road (maybe even binary - why serialize at all if you're worried about speed)